# Ghost directory in home directory

Tags: directory, disk-usage

I am using following command to check the disk usage in my home direcory.

```
du -sk * | sort -n
```

I am getting the following output

```
273240  AQP
707720  oradiag
3176872 J2EEServer
23628720        var
100000910
```

I get a directory of size 100000910 without a name in the last line . How can I access/delete this ghost directory in my home directory.

Comment: I have only 4 folders in my home directory .I don't know from where  I am getting that extra line.

Answer (score 6):

The directory name might be composed of space characters (spaces, tabs...). With GNU coreutils (linux standard) use `ls -Q` which will put the filenames into quotes. Or check with a filemanager like Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the name of the directory is ? (that is a space, or a tab). This is a perfectly correct Unix filename. Why don't you run

```
ls -Ql
```

And check for yourself?

Comment: With ls -l, you will be able to see the directory, but no way of know if its one space, to spaces, a tab, etc.

Comment: good point. I add the -Q option.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the file is composed entirely of non-printable or whitespace characters. You can probably see it using `printf '<%q>\n' *`.

You should be able to get the inode number using `ls -il`. After that, you can remove it by using something like `find . -xdev -maxdepth 1 -inum 1234 -delete`. Given its size, the directory is probably not empty; you can change into it to examine it with `cd "$(find . -xdev -maxdepth 1 -inum 1234)"` to examine the contents at your leasure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `ls -al` see if the file is there as well.